# Add polyline to react-hook-google-maps

Tags: typescript, google-maps, react-hooks

I have a simple code where I render google maps. I am having trouble adding polyline to it.

```
import React from "react";
import { useGoogleMaps } from "react-hook-google-maps";

export const Map = React.memo(function Map() {  
  const pointA = {  lat: 0, lng: -180 };
  var polyline = require( 'google-polyline' );
  const { ref, map, google } = useGoogleMaps(
    "YOUR_API_KEY",
    {
      zoom: 4,
      center: pointA,
    },
  );
 if (map) {
   var poly = polyline.decode('_jpeFn||hVf}qcBvnixEfwtoF_fic_Afh|w@~u`zC');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(poly));
  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: poly,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
  }); 
  polyline.setMap(map);
  }

return (
    <div>
      <div ref={ref} style={{ width: 600, height: 400 }} />
    </div>
  );
});
```

How can I add the given polyline on the map? In case you want decoded version of the polyline.

```
const poly = [
    { lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214 },
    { lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821 },
    { lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431 },
    { lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027 },
  ];
```

I am using typescript. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my code is right. Apparently, my

```
var poly = polyline.decode('_jpeFn||hVf}qcBvnixEfwtoF_fic_Afh|w@~u`zC');
```

gives an array of arrays instead of arrays of objects. So the code below must be added to convert array of arrays to array of objects.

```
var poly1 = poly.map(function(x: any) { 
    return { 
      lat: x[0], 
      lng: x[1] 
    };
  });
```